# Is there something like a QueryUnload event in WPF page-based apps?

Tags: wpf

I'm working on my first WPF app, using VS 2008.  When I worked in VB6, there was a form event called **QueryUnload**, which one could use to determine how an application was shutting down.  I'd like to do the same thing in a page-based WPF application, if that's possible.  (My app is not an XBAP application, but a page-based app.)  I know that VB6 didn't have anything like a page-based application, so it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it in your handler for `Window.Closing`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743714.aspx#Application_Shutdown)